# Closed Lie subgroups

Tags: lie-groups

Suppose that $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is a lie group homomorphism. How do I show that $\ker(\phi)$ is a closed subgroup of $G$? In general, when we refer to $H \leq G$ being closed, do we mean that $H$ is closed under the topology associated with $G$? Assuming that $\phi$ is a continuous map, we have that $\phi^{-1}(1) = \ker(\phi)$, since the inverse of a closed set is closed, we have that $\ker(\phi)$ is closed. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Is it true that if $H \leq G$ is a closed lie subgroup, then it is an embedded lie subgroup?

Comment: Yes, actually something stronger is true: If $H$ is an abstract subgroup of $G$ (i.e. a subgroup but not necesarilly a Lie subgroup) and $H$ is a closed subset of $G$, then $H$ is an embedded Lie subgroup of $G$. It is a highly non trivial theorem known as the closed subgroup theorem. You may want to take a look to Warner's book or to Knapp's book on Lie groups.